# ruby map a function over multiple arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, iteration, idioms

I have 2 arrays

```rb
   asc = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
   dsc = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

I want a new array that is results of multiplying each corresponding item in asc and dsc

I'm used to Clojure where I would just `map`

```clj
(map #(* %1 %2) asc dsc) ;=> (0 4 6 6 4 0)
```

Is their an equivalent in Ruby, what would be the idiomatic way to do this in Ruby?

I'm new to Ruby but it seems to have really nice concise solutions, so I assume I'm missing something.

Do I just write:

```rb
i = 0
res = []

while i < asc.length() do
  res.append(asc[i] * dsc[i])
end
```

Comment: You forgot commas in `asc` and `dsc`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [zip](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-zip) to combine each element with its corresponding in two element array and than map

```
asc.zip(dsc).map { |a, b| a * b }
 => [0, 4, 6, 6, 4, 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-map) and [`with_index`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerator/with_index):

```
asc = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
dsc = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
res = asc.map.with_index{ |el, i| el * dsc[i] }
puts res.inspect
# [0, 4, 6, 6, 4, 0]
```

Alternatively, use [`each_index`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/each_index) and [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-map):

```
res = asc.each_index.map{ |i| asc[i] * dsc[i] }
```

Comment: I think `zip` would be more commonly used, but it has the disadvantage, compared to your answer, of creating a temporary array (`asc.zip(dsc)`). You could instead write this `asc.each_index.map { |i| asc[i] * dsc[i] }` (though I don't think either is preferred).

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thank you for suggesting another solution! I added it to my answer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland another way to avoid the temporary array is `asc.enum_for(:zip, dsc)`

Answer (score 2):

It appears that `dsc` ("descending") is derived from `asc` ("ascending"), in which case you could write:

```
asc.each_index.map { |i| asc[i] * asc[-i-1] } 
  #=> [0, 4, 6, 6, 4, 0]
```

You could also write:

```
[asc, dsc].transpose.map { |a,d| a*d }
  #=> [0, 4, 6, 6, 4, 0]
```

or:

```
require 'matrix'

Matrix[asc].hadamard_product(Matrix[dsc]).to_a.first
  #=> [0, 4, 6, 6, 4, 0]
```

See [Matrix#hadamard_product](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.8/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-i-hadamard_product).

Answer (score 2):

You could also write like below:

```
asc = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
dsc = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]

p asc.zip(dsc).collect{|z| z.inject(:*)}
[0, 4, 6, 6, 4, 0]
```